# Writing directly to buffer of a bits field

Tags: python, buffer, bit-fields

I am working on bits fields structure from ctypes in Python and I have a question.
Is it possible to write directly to the buffer of the Packet Union below defined ?

```
from ctypes import c_uint8

class PacketBits(ctypes.LittleEndianStructure):
  _fields_ = [
      # First byte
      ("a", ctypes.c_uint8, 4),
      ("b", ctypes.c_uint8, 3),
      ("c", ctypes.c_uint8, 1),
      # Second byte
      ("d", ctypes.c_uint8, 5),
      ("e", ctypes.c_uint8, 3),
      # Third byte
      ("f", ctypes.c_uint8, 4),
      ("g", ctypes.c_uint8, 4),
      # Fourth byte
      ("h", ctypes.c_uint8, 2),
      ("i", ctypes.c_uint8, 6),
      # Fifth byte
      ("j", ctypes.c_uint8, 4),
      ("k", ctypes.c_uint8, 3),
      ("l", ctypes.c_uint8, 1),
      # Sixth byte
      ("m", ctypes.c_uint8, 5),
      ("n", ctypes.c_uint8, 3),
      # Seventh byte
      ("o", ctypes.c_uint8, 4),
      ("p", ctypes.c_uint8, 4),
      # Eighth byte
      ("q", ctypes.c_uint8, 2),
      ("r", ctypes.c_uint8, 6),
  ]

class Packet(ctypes.Union):
    _fields_ = [("bits", PacketBits),
                ("binary_data", 8 * c_uint8)]
```

I ask this question because I need to parse a stream of 65 bytes with some bits definitions inside.

I have tried to set it directly, with a bitarray, ... and all methods that I tried was unsuccesfull.

Anyone have an idea ?

Best regards.

Johan

Comment: Correction : I want to write directly to binary_data and not buffer in the Union

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, I used setter and getter in Packet class:

```
class Packet(ctypes.Union):
    _fields_ = [("bits", PacketBits),
                ("binary_data", 8 * ctypes.c_uint8)]

    def get_binary_data(self):
        data = []
        for byte in self.binary_data:
            data.append(byte) 

        return data

    def set_binary_data(self, data = b'\x0D\x0E\x0A\x0D\x0B\x0E\x0E\x0F'):
        if len(data) <= len(self.binary_data):
            for index in range(len(data)):
                self.binary_data[index] = data[index]
```

But now when I instantiate the Packet class I have access to binary_data, setter and getter.

Then there is two access to binary_data.

I want to allow one access (by setter and getter) then I tried with property like this:

```
class Packet(ctypes.Union):
    _fields_ = [("bits", PacketBits),
                ("binary_data", 8 * ctypes.c_uint8)]

    @property
    def binary_data(self):
        data = []
        for byte in self.binary_data:
            data.append(byte) 

        return data

    @binary_data.setter
    def binary_data(self, data = b'\x0D\x0E\x0A\x0D\x0B\x0E\x0E\x0F'):
        if len(data) <= len(self.binary_data):
            for index in range(len(data)):
                self.binary_data[index] = data[index]

In [2]: p = Packet()

In [3]: p.binary_data()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-5caaf0aaa9ce> in <module>()
----> 1 p.binary_data()

TypeError: 'c_ubyte_Array_8' object is not callable

In [4]: p.binary_data
Out[4]: <test.c_ubyte_Array_8 at 0x7f7d538bf400>

In [5]: p.binary_data = b'\xaa'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-6a26479e789c> in <module>()
----> 1 p.binary_data = b'\xaa'

TypeError: expected c_ubyte_Array_8 instance, got bytes
```

Anyone have a idea how to properly use property and setter ?

Johan